# SQL Server auto Id for a View result

Tags: sql-server

We are using below view to generate identity column values using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, but how would I change this view to return incremental numbers in identity column, for example if I run view today it will return 100 records and the identity column value is from 1 to 100, if I run it tomorrow, it should return 101 to whatever the records it has in that day.greatly appreciate your help.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Data_Old] 
AS
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_time) AS id,
        event_time, loc, c, d, e, f, Expr1
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             FORMAT(h.ACTIVITYDT, 'yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss') AS event_time, 
             ISNULL(h.LOCATION, N'17.51.12.24') loc, 
             ' LEEF:1.0|Manage|WorkSite|9.5|' + CAST(NEWID() AS varchar(50)) c, 
             '|devTime=' + FORMAT(h.ACTIVITYDT, 'MMM dd hh:mm:ss') d, 
             '|usrName=' + ISNULL(h.USER, N'{null}') + '|fullName=' + ISNULL(u.FULLNAME, N'{null}') e, 
             '|activity=' + ISNULL(h.ACTIVITYDT, N'{null}') + '|library=COLLECTIONS' + '|Num=' + CAST(h.NUM AS varchar) + '|version=' + CAST(h.VERSION AS varchar) f, 
             '|pagesPrinted=' + CAST(h.PAGES_PRINTED AS varchar) + '|FTI=' + ISNULL(CAST(d.CBOOL2 AS varchar), N'False') 
                              + '|keyData=case:' + ISNULL(d.C5ALIAS, N'{null}') + ';serialNo:' + ISNULL(d.C16ALIAS, N'{null}') 
                              + ';documentNo:' + ISNULL(CAST(d.CDBL1 AS varchar), N'') AS Expr1
         FROM 
             dbo.HISTORY AS h 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             dbo.MASTERS AS d WITH (nolock) ON d.NUM = h.NUM AND d.VERSION = h.VERSION 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             dbo.USERS AS u WITH (nolock) ON h.USER = u.USERID
         WHERE 
             (h.ACTIVITYDT >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
              AND h.ACTIVITYDT < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) 
             AND (h.ACTIVITYDT >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
                  AND h.ACTIVITYDT < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) 
             AND (h.ACTIVITYDT >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
                  AND h.ACTIVITYDT < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) 

         UNION ALL

         SELECT  
             FORMAT(ACTIONDT, 'yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss') AS event_time, 
             ' 127.55.82.124' b, 
             ' LEEF:1.0|Manage|WorkSite|9.5|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SID) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(SECOND, ACTIONDT, '2017-01-01')) c,
             '|devTime=' + FORMAT(ACTIONDT, 'MMM dd hh:mm:ss') d,
             '|usrName=' + ISNULL(USERID, '{null}') e,
             '|activity=' + CASE ACTIONSID       
                               WHEN 1 THEN 'Successful Login' 
                               WHEN 2 THEN 'Unsuccessful Login' 
                               WHEN 3 THEN 'Impersonated Login' 
                               WHEN 4 THEN 'Impersonated Logoff' 
                            END f, 
             '|library=COLLECTIONS' AS LEEF
         FROM 
             dbo.HISTORY
         WHERE 
             (ACTIONDT >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
              AND ACTIONDT < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) 
             AND (ACTIONDT >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
                  AND ACTIONDT < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) 
             AND (ACTIONDT >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
                  AND ACTIONDT < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) 
        ) AS MyResult
```

Comment: row_number is going to give you a number for every row. So if you have 101 rows, the ID's will be 1-101. How your force only 101 or how ever many rows to be returned is up to you.

Comment: 1-101 are single day records, next day If I have another 100 records I want the identity number should start from 101 to 200

Comment: Well since view's aren't materialized, you'd have to log the output of the execution of the previous day and then add it to your row_number so that you can keep a running total. Not really sure what the end game is here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the ROW_NUMBER() over the entire table in a CTE without a WHERE clause.

Then to look at only today's data, select from the CTE and use a WHERE clause.

Your current code applies the WHERE clause first (in the derived table) and then uses ROW_NUMBER() over those filtered results, so the Row Number will always start at 1.   You need to do the opposite.